# Edit dash size in links? (Dashes invisible in thick links)

Tags: netlogo

In NetLogo 6.1.1, in the link editor, there are four line styles: solid, dotted, dashed, and a more complex dashed pattern.

However, when the visual representation of a link is thick, the spaces between dashes become invisible.  It seems that the thickening surrounds each point in every direction, so that in thick lines, the color of the line overlaps the space between dashes.

Is there any way to edit dashes to create more space (or to produce better behavior for thick lines)?